# Catch plugin error javascript

Tags: javascript, plugins, error-handling

I'm using a plugin and I want to handle the errors throws. In special occasions, my script gets error and the cause is a line of code in the plugin:

```
...
if (!element) {
    throw new Error('Container does not exist: ' + container);
} 
...
```

Plugin failing its function is not a problem, but it stops the rest of my script (which is a problem). So I wanted to use `try{}catch(e){}` to avoid my script stopping.

```
<script src="plugin.js"></script>
<script> 
//This is my script structure
var object = $('#element');
doSomething();

function doSomething(){
try {
//Here I call the plugin function...
object.pluginAction(options);
} catch(err) {
//Here's the code I want to exec if plugin function fail
console.log('Plugin error: '+err);
}
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. I still get the error in chrome console and no log and script crashes... How can I handle that error without editing the plugin source?
Thank you

Comment: Is the 'throw' statement in the plugin wrapped in its own try..catch block?

Comment: @JasonFetterly Nope...

Comment: Well, all I can think off is somewhere along the line there is a try..catch that executes before yours.  If you can post a jsfiddle, might be able to help further...